# Dynamically resize width of input Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Need to dynamically change the width of the input, and so that the suffix meters (m) was always near the number that I enter. Also need to  passing some value to input via value = "something"
then the width of the input need to be  expanded depending on the transmitted value.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-af5yt7?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to create a directive to update the width, but why build this yourself? No need to reinvent the wheel, use some existing package like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-autosize-input

Comment: this package is not working for me because a have angular 8, and this package for 10+

Comment: you can install a previous version: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-autosize-input/v/2.3.7